# Why is my VGG-19 implementation not performing well?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, pytorch, vgg-net

I have to implement VGG-19 manually in order to have the best accuracy rate on CIFAR-10 data test.

I read the paper about VGGNet and implemented the VGG-19 network but I have an accuracy rate of 10% on the test dataset... I tried changing Batch size, learning rate with no improvement.

```py
class MyClassifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
        super(MyClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv22 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv32 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv42 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)


        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.Dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=512*1*1, out_features=4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=output_dim)

  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
      x = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv12(x)))

      x = self.relu(self.conv2(x))
      x = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv22(x)))

      x = self.relu(self.conv3(x))
      x = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv32(x)))

      x = self.relu(self.conv4(x))
      x = self.relu(self.conv42(x))
      x = self.relu(self.conv42(x))
      x = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv42(x)))

      x = self.relu(self.conv42(x))
      x = self.relu(self.conv42(x))
      x = self.relu(self.conv42(x))
      x = self.pool(self.relu(self.conv42(x)))

      x = x.view(-1, 512*1*1)
      x = self.Dropout(self.relu(self.fc1(x)))
      x = self.Dropout(self.relu(self.fc2(x)))
      outputs = self.fc3(x)
      return outputs
```

Here are my results:

```py
[epoch:0, iteration:2000] train loss : 2.5708 train accuracy : 0.0000
[epoch:0, iteration:4000] train loss : 2.4595 train accuracy : 0.0000
[epoch:0, iteration:6000] train loss : 2.2051 train accuracy : 0.0000
[epoch:0, iteration:8000] train loss : 2.4449 train accuracy : 0.0000
[epoch:0, iteration:10000] train loss : 2.3113 train accuracy : 0.2500
[epoch:0, iteration:12000] train loss : 2.3602 train accuracy : 0.0000
[epoch:0, iteration:12500] test_loss : 2.3092 test accuracy : 0.1000
checkpoint is saved !
```

My test accuracy is 0.1 (10%) at epoch:0 but stays 0.1 even after 10 epochs. I believed I could achieve at least 0.8 (80%) with VGG-19's code. 
Do you see any problem with the code or is it something else ?

Comment: What do you mean by regularizing inputs ? I have used :
transform_test = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

Also I use the same Maxpool and Relu function so I don't need to declare them again. I only declared them once and then use them several times.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would think it has something to do with your loss function during training. Are you using Cross-Entropy loss? If you're using NLLLoss, you need a log softmax layer at the end of your network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am using cross entropy